# Debugging a gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, pry

I have a gem, nanoc, which I'd like to debug.

Its command line, `nanoc` executes the following script (in /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'nanoc' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'nanoc', version
load Gem.bin_path('nanoc', 'nanoc', version)
```

which itself loads at the last line what is resolved as (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nanoc-3.6.2/bin)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

# Try loading bundler if it's possible
begin
  require 'bundler/setup'
rescue LoadError
  # no problem
end

# Add lib to load path
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib'))

# Load nanoc
require 'nanoc'
require 'nanoc/cli'

# Run base
Nanoc::CLI.run(ARGV)
```

What are the least intrusive options to debug those kind of scripts ?
If I just pry the first file, ARGV will be the filename itself..

Do I have to modify files only to run a debugger ?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not sure I undestand the question.  You could just put your pry inside the lib for nanoc.

Alternatively, you could just fork the git repo, and then clone it and run the gem with it's bundle and debug that way as well:

`https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc`

Clone the repo, add your debug code, and then run `bundle exec bin/nanoc` that way you are keeping your locally installed copy clean.  Once you figure out what is wrong, you can build a new gem, install it, commit the code, and make a pull request to fix it for everybody.

Comment: i have an exception in a filter (some nanoc concept), inside the lib. I wonder how to put a breakpoint easily.